# useRef is always null until I update and save my code

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a `useRef` on a tag to get the width value. But when the page is loaded, `ref` is always `null`. The only time it gets the value, it's when I update my code and save it inside my IDE. This is the current code :

```js
import { Navbar } from './Navbar';
import photo from './assets/photo.jpg';
import shoes from './assets/shoes.jpg';
import jump from './assets/jump.jpg';
import { getShoes } from './Request';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Loader } from './Loader';

export const Home = () => {
    const { data, isSuccess } = useQuery('shoes', getShoes);
    const [carouselMaxWidth, setCarouselMaxWidth] = useState<number>(0);
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(ref);
        if (ref && ref.current) {
            const tmp = ref.current?.scrollWidth - ref.current?.offsetWidth;
            setCarouselMaxWidth(() => tmp);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {isSuccess ? (
                <div className='h-screen'>
                        <div ref={ref} className='overflow-x-hidden'>
                            <motion.div
                                className='flex min-w-fit space-x-5 cursor-grab'
                                drag='x'
                                dragConstraints={{ right: 0, left: -carouselMaxWidth }}
                                style={{ width: carouselMaxWidth }}
                            >
                                {data.slice(0, 10).map((i: any, key: number) => {
                                    return (
                                        <motion.div className='h-full w-96 pointer-events-none' key={key}>
                                            <img src={i.img} alt={i.title} className='object-cover h-96 w-96' />
                                            <div className='flex justify-between'>
                                                <div>
                                                    <span>{i.title}</span>
                                                    <div className='text-opacity-50'>{i.source}</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <span>{i.price}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </motion.div>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </motion.div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <Loader />
            )}
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: are you sure useEffect run before isSuccess is true?. You should pass isSuccess into the array dependencies of useEffect

Comment: @HuấnNguyễnXuân oh god, I updated my code to had is `isSuccess` and completely forgot this. Thank you !!